# Unable to hide/suppress output of a "net user" command

Tags: command-line, powershell

I've tried a bunch of different solutions, including but not limited to the following. I want to suppress the output no matter what as I plan to use the Powershell variable $LastExitCode to figure out whether the command executed successfully or not.

```
NET USER Alice | Out-Null

NET USER Alice > $null
```

None of these solutions seem to suppress the following output which is seen when the account does not exist.

```
PS C:\> net user Alice
The user name could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.
```

Is there anyway I can suppress this output ?

Comment: Does this work? [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816502/how-to-hide-output-from-net-use-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

> net user Alice > $null 2>&1

This should work, output should suppressed with any existing or non-existing username.

Comment: Thanks @Aulis, can you please help me understand how this works ? I get that  1 = STDOUT, 2 = STDERR and we're basically writing $null to both of those standard pipes, correct ?

Comment: Read `Get-Help about_redirection`

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar: You can find long explanations in Linux/Unix-oriented sites, as that's where the redirection syntax originally comes from. Yes, it first redirects STDOUT to $null, then STDERR to STDOUT (which at this point is $null).

Comment: I see that @grawity has already explained the function way better than I ever could. Thank you!